# MySQL Call in loop

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, call

I have created a Stored Procedure, that looks like this:

```
DELIMITER €€
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetAllNonprocessedSMSes`()
   BEGIN
      DECLARE smsid INT(10);
      DECLARE finish BOOLEAN;

      DECLARE id_cur CURSOR FOR
         SELECT id FROM (
            SELECT
               MIN(id) as id,
               MIN(UDH) as udh,
               MIN(LENGTH(TextDecoded)) as txtlen,
               MAX(ReceivingDateTime)-DATE_ADD(MIN(ReceivingDateTime), INTERVAL 3 MINUTE) AS rcvtimeout
            FROM inbox
            WHERE
               Processed='false'
            GROUP BY
               IF(UDH='',id,SUBSTR(UDH,1,10))
            HAVING
               rcvtimeout>0
               OR udh=''
               OR txtlen<156
         ) AS baseview
         ORDER BY id;

      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finish = TRUE;
      OPEN id_cur;

      the_loop : LOOP
         FETCH id_cur INTO smsid;
         CALL GetSMS(smsid);

         IF finish THEN
            CLOSE id_cur;
            LEAVE the_loop;
     END IF;
      END LOOP the_loop;
   END €€
DELIMITER ;
```

I know the cursor selects more than one row, but when I call the Procedure it only returns one entry, but when it is runned it only returns the first entry. 
How can I fix that?

**EDIT**
The `GetSMS` Stored Procedure looks like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetSMS`(IN smsid int(10))
   BEGIN
      DECLARE smsudh TEXT;
      SELECT `UDH` INTO smsudh FROM `inbox` WHERE `ID`=smsid;
      IF (STRCMP(smsudh, '') < 1) THEN
         SELECT * FROM `inbox` WHERE `ID`=smsid;
      ELSE
         SELECT * FROM `inbox` WHERE `UDH` LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(smsudh, (LENGTH(smsudh)-2)), "%") GROUP BY `ID` ORDER BY `UDH`;
      END IF;
   END €€
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you then figure out if there are any ways to create the GetSMS
>   Procedure as one SELECT-statement, so I can create it like INSERT INTO
>   tmptable SELECT ... – The87Boy 3 mins ago

#  put into  PROCEDURE `GetAllNonprocessedSMSes`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable;
CREATE TABLE TempTable LIKE `inbox`;
```

# then, in GetSMS

```
  IF (STRCMP(smsudh, '') < 1) THEN
     INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT * FROM `inbox` WHERE `ID`=smsid;
  ELSE
     INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT * FROM `inbox` WHERE `UDH` LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(smsudh, (LENGTH(smsudh)-2)), "%") GROUP BY `ID` ORDER BY `UDH`;
  END IF;
```

You might want to put a lock around TempTable so that you don't run two copies of the procedure concurrently.

Comment: btw,  IF (STRCMP(smsudh, '') < 1) ... can't you use the LENGTH function here?.  This is very suspicious.

Comment: I figured out a better solution for the SELECT-statement which is `SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE ID=smsid OR IF(UDH='', ID=smsid, LEFT(UDH, 10)=LEFT((SELECT UDH FROM inbox WHERE ID=smsid), 10))` but is it possible to optimize that query?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on in your function GetSMS, but have you ever tried wrapping it up like

```
select 
      GetSMS( baseQuery.ID )
   from
      ( your current query ) baseQuery
```

I don't know what GetSMS may return, as long as it returns SOMETHING, even 1, true, "", then you just ignore the results of the query result, but each qualified ID from your query will be passed as the argument to the function.

Comment: It says the function GetSMS do not exist, as it is a Stored Procedure

Comment: @The87Boy, I'll have to get into another machine to try and get MySQL running, but another question, and I honestly don't do stored procedures... but with respect to "handlers" (not found) and variables... is the "finish" causing some conflict? and falsely getting set from WITHIN your call to GetSMS?

Comment: I have tested with a Temporary table and that worked. Perhaps it is possible to write the GetSMS Procedure as one where-statement, but I can not figure that out. Or perhaps making `GetAllNonprocessedSMSes` into one query

Answer (score 0):

I really can't see what you are trying to accomplish, but there are a few problems here.

1) Your terminating condition is wrong.

```
  DECLARE finish BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0; # <- set up initial conditions
  ...
  the_loop : LOOP
     FETCH id_cur INTO smsid;

     IF finish THEN
        CLOSE id_cur;
        LEAVE the_loop;
     END IF

     CALL GetSMS(smsid);  # <- move the call to GetSMS after the finish, or it will be called with an invalid record.
```

2) The call to GetSMS returns a selection for each call.  These selections will be returned separately to the client. You need to figure some way of concatenating them to a single table.

Comment: Oh, I followed a guide that described, that it should be before, but I can not find the guide now. Do you have any idea of how I can concate them into a single table?

Comment: At the moment, no, other than creating a temporary table and inserting them.  ie,  INSERT INTO TempTable(field1, field2) SELECT (asfield1, asfield2) .....;  then, SELECT * FROM TempTable;  DROP TABLE TempTable; at the end to send the results back to the client.

Comment: Can you then figure out if there are any ways to create the `GetSMS` Procedure as one SELECT-statement, so I can create it like `INSERT INTO tmptable SELECT ...`